# html2canvas and flashcanvas on IE8 not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-8, html2canvas, flashcanvas

I use html2canvas library to make a png image of a table.

*It works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.*

The code is as follows:

```
$('#myTable').html2canvas ({     
    onrendered : function(canvas) {                           
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var newWin = window.open('', '_blank','width=500,height=400');
        var htmlPage = "";
        htmlPage += "<html>";
        htmlPage += "<head>";
        ...
        htmlPage += "</head>";
        htmlPage += "<body>";
        ...   
        htmlPage += "<img src='"+img+"' width='400px'/>";
        ...   
        htmlPage += "</body>";
        htmlPage += "</html>";
        newWin.document.write(htmlPage);
    }
});
```

When I open the page with **IE8 the page does not work.**

I have read that I should use flashcanvas, so I added the flashcanvas library and added this row in the page:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>                
   <script type="text/javascript src="../sample/flashcanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

So, when I open the page with IE8, the library flashcanvas.js was loaded!

But the problem remains! IE8 tells me:

```
"The object does not support the property or the method 'toDataURL'"
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure how the `canvas` element is created, but you might need to do something like this inside the `onrendered` callback:

```
if (typeof FlashCanvas != "undefined") {
    FlashCanvas.initElement(canvas);
}
var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
// etc...
```

See the docs here: http://flashcanvas.net/docs/usage

Comment: The error now is different: << SCRIPT16389: Error not specified.
flashcanvas.js, Row 24 Column 56 >>

Comment: Looks like an unspecified error in the flashcanvas.js file :)