# How can I do a preview of some HTML part of my code as PDF or DOCX file in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, pdf

I have some data that I should present on a container like if it is a PDF or DOCX file with separated pages. But I don't have PDF or DOCX at the moment. I have HTML code and in some `div` at the same page I should add such kind of preview so user could see how it will be exported to PDF or DOCX file. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution yet. I tried with `embed` and `iframe` but it requires data different from simple HTML code. How can I achieve simple HTML code be previewed as PDF or DOCX? I'm using Angular 9 on my project.

Comment: May be help https://stackoverflow.com/q/13875498/6438494

Comment: OR https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: Thx, but those are not an answer to my question. I need to present my HTML code as PDF without downloading PDF file or any other file.

Comment: you can make html to pdf using pdf.js (https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-convert-html-page-to-pdf-in-angular-application) and then to view that pdf in web u can use ng2-pdf-viewer https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: @MskSatheesh will it also use styles from scss file and split correctly to pages if I have no pages in HTML?

Comment: i think this stackblitz example will help you i think https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css  . You can check your thing here...